# Is it possible to specify TableRow height?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, row-height

I have a `TableLayout` with multiple `TableRow` views inside it.  I wish to specify the height of the row programatically.  E.g.

```
int rowHeight = calculateRowHeight();
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(activity);
TableRow tableRow = buildTableRow();
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, rowHeight);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow, rowLp);
```

But this isn't working and is defaulting to WRAP_CONTENT.  Digging around in the [Android source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TableLayout.java), I see this in `TableLayout` (triggered by the onMeasure() method):

```
private void findLargestCells(int widthMeasureSpec) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TableRow) {
            final TableRow row = (TableRow) child;
            // forces the row's height
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = row.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Seems like any attempt to set the row height will be overridden by the TableLayout.  Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I think I've got the hang of this now.  The way to set the height of the row is not to fiddle with the `TableLayout.LayoutParams` attached to the `TableRow`, but the `TableRow.LayoutParams` attached to *any* of the cells.  Simply make one cell the desired height and (assuming its the tallest cell) the entire row will be that height.  In my case, I added an extra 1 pixel wide column set to the desired height which did the trick:

```
View spacerColumn = new View(activity);
//add the new column with a width of 1 pixel and the desired height
tableRow.addView(spacerColumn, new TableRow.LayoutParams(1, rowHeight));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You should convert it from dps to pixels using the display factor formula.

```
  final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 

  int trHeight = (int) (30 * scale + 0.5f);
  int trWidth = (int) (67 * scale + 0.5f); 
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutpParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(trWidth, trHeight);
  tableRow.setLayoutParams(layoutpParams);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the last line of the quoted code above (see ``findLargestCells()``) in the TableLayout source code resets the height of the ViewGroup.LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT regardless of what I specify.