# .getLayoutParams().height not working for table rows of a tablelayout but works for the textview inside the table cells

Tags: android, tablelayout

In an Android application, I set up a TableLayout with 2 rows each row with 2 columns and each cell contains a textview

I set the height of each TextView with the following code:
`myTextview1.getLayoutParams().height = val`

And the row height for each row changes accordingly

The point is I can't change the row height if I use the same code for table rows in this way:
`myRow1.getLayoutParams().height= val`

Why?

Comment: check this out, i think it solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445980/is-it-possible-to-specify-tablerow-height

Comment: Unfortunately not, the point is I use XML file to set up the table and the get the layoutparms and then set height but in the link the addview is used to add the rows

Comment: The height used by a TableRow inside a TableLayout will always be WRAP_CONTENT. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout